# How to create the same timer for multiple views in ios ?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I am trying to create a test app that has a timer for all the views. I could create a timer for one view but I don't know how to implement it for multiple views. Anyone knows how to create one or any solutions?

Comment: What are you going to use the timer for?

Answer (score 0):

Create the timer so that when it fires it targets the app delegate. The app delegate can then post a *notification* to broadcast to multiple objects simultaneously.